# 'uint32_t' identifier not found error

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm porting code from Linux C to Visual C++ for windows.

Visual C++ doesn't know `#include <stdint.h>` so I commented it out.

Later, I found a lot of those `'uint32_t': identifier not found` errors. How can it be solved?

Comment: Which include are you commenting out?

Comment: And, which version(s) of Visual C++ are you using?  The `uint32_t` and other exact-width integer types are only part of C99 and C++0x, so older compilers (like Visual C++ 2008 and earlier) don't have them.

Comment: Quite a lot !!! #include <stdint.h> #include <syslog.h> #include <linux/stddef.h> #include <pthread.h> #include <unistd.h> Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ express 2008 .

Comment: so what should I do if My VC ++ 2008 doesn't know those type ??? Any advise for me ?

Comment: @kevin: You can't just remove platform-specific headers and forget about them. You have to find alternatives for the new platform. This often involves some amount of rewriting your code in order to make it portable.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This type is defined in the C header `<stdint.h>` which is part of the C++11 standard but not standard in C++03.  According to [the Wikipedia page on the header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h), it hasn't shipped with Visual Studio until VS2010.

In the meantime, you could probably fake up your own version of the header by adding `typedef`s that map [Microsoft's custom integer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) to the types expected by C.  For example:

```
typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
/* ... etc. ... */
```

Comment: You can also use Boost's cstdint implementation.

Comment: I copy and paste your code on my page. But it shows this error "syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'int32_t'" and "missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int".

Comment: Sorry Peter, I'm new to C . What is Boost's cstdint implementation?

Comment: Boost is a collection of C++ libraries (one of which implements the C99 stdint.h header that you're after).  If you're sticking with C, I'd go with either defining your own or using one of the alternative implementations referenced by the Wikipedia article that templatetypedef linked (such as http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h).

Comment: Microsoft's fixed-size integer types don't end in "t".  Try just `__int32`.

Comment: 'u_int32_t' : undeclared identifier error again !! is it the same with uint32_t? or another type ?

Comment: `u_int32_t` and `uint32_t` are not the same type; one has an extra underscore after the `u`.  That seems like a separate problem.

Comment: Even in VS2010 I haven't been able to find the symbols in the help file.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Last I checked `__int32` is *not* cross-platform compatible.

Comment: @Di-0xide: My comment was in context of this answer, which creates a platform-specific header file that defines the portable typedefs.  To do so, you need to know the platform-specific names.

Comment: Although you're right that the Microsoft compilers don't include stdint.h I coudln't find that statement at the referenced Wikipedia page.

Comment: As i just ran into this problem, if you are using a version of Visual Studio that does include this file, you can probably include it in your precompiled header, or specify "stdint.h" as a forced include file in the project properties

Comment: I think the `typedef`s shouldbe wrapped in some `#ifdef`

Answer (score 99):

You can `#include <cstdint>`. It's part of C++-standard since 2011.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer given the question's constraints, like C++ and VS2010. There's no need to roll your own typedef's.

Comment: @jww look at the date on the question and the compiler version the OP was using.  This is a great answer today, but wasn't appropriate to the original question.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same error and it fixed it including in the file the following

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

at the beginning of your file.

Comment: As pointed out in the question, *stdint.h* is not part of the C++ compiler the OP is using. This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 7):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Config](http://www.boost.org/libs/config/) offers these typedefs for toolsets that do not provide them natively. The documentation for this specific functionality is here: [Standard Integer Types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/cstdint.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation available at the [msinttypes project page](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/) - "This project fills the absence of stdint.h and inttypes.h in Microsoft Visual Studio".

I don't have experience with this implementation, but I've seen it recommended by others on SO.

Comment: This the better and most commonly implementation used.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I usually use windows types. To use it you have to include `<Windows.h>`.

In this case uint32_t is UINT32 or just UINT.

All types definitions are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I had to run project in VS2010 and I could not introduce any modifications in the code. My solution was to install vS2013 and in VS2010 point VC++ Directories->IncludeDirectories to Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include. Then my project compiled without any issues.