# Compiling C++ Thrift code to interface Cassandra results in following errors. What are we missing here?

Tags: c++, cassandra, thrift

```
         
    $ g++ -lthrift -Wall thriftfs.cpp cassandra_constants.cpp Cassandra.cpp cassandra_types.cpp -o thriftfs -I/usr/local/include/thrift -L/usr/local/lib


        In file included from /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h:23:0,
                         from /usr/local/include/thrift/TProcessor.h:24,
                         from Cassandra.h:10,
                         from t`enter code here`hriftfs.cpp:4:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TTransport.h:34:1: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        /usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TTransport.h:156:29: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘buf’ with no type [-fpermissive]

        In file included from /usr/local/include/thrift/TProcessor.h:24:0,
                         from Cassandra.h:10,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h:184:1: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        In file included from Cassandra.h:10:0,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/TProcessor.h:72:57: error: ‘uint32_t’ has not been declared

        In file included from cassandra_types.h:11:0,
                         from Cassandra.h:11,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/TApplicationException.h:94:3: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        In file included from Cassandra.h:11:0,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        cassandra_types.h:85:16: error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type
        In file included from Cassandra.h:11:0,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        cassandra_types.h:142:3: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        In file included from Cassandra.h:11:0,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        cassandra_types.h:1478:16: error: ‘uint8_t’ does not name a type
        In file included from Cassandra.h:11:0,
                         from thriftfs.cpp:4:
        cassandra_types.h:1812:3: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        In file included from thriftfs.cpp:4:0:
        Cassandra.h:217:3: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

        Cassandra.h:4857:35: error: ‘org::apache::thrift’ has not been declared
        Cassandra.h:4857:62: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
        Cassandra.h:4859:71: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘void’ member
        Cassandra.h:4859:145: error: template argument 2 is invalid
        Cassandra.h:4859:145: error: template argument 4 is invalid
        Cassandra.h:4860:45: error: ‘org::apache::thrift’ has not been declared
        Cassandra.h:4860:72: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token

        Cassandra.h:4935:42: error: ‘thrift’ is not a member of ‘org::apache’
        Cassandra.h:4935:42: note: suggested alternative:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/Thrift.h:75:37: note:   ‘apache::thrift’
        Cassandra.h:4935:42: error: ‘thrift’ is not a member of ‘org::apache’
        Cassandra.h:4935:42: note: suggested alternative:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/Thrift.h:75:37: note:   ‘apache::thrift’
        Cassandra.h:4935:77: error: template argument 1 is invalid
        Cassandra.h:4935:105: error: ‘thrift’ is not a member of ‘org::apache’
        Cassandra.h:4935:105: note: suggested alternative:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/Thrift.h:75:37: note:   ‘apache::thrift’
        Cassandra.h:4935:105: error: ‘thrift’ is not a member of ‘org::apache’
        Cassandra.h:4935:105: note: suggested alternative:
        /usr/local/include/thrift/Thrift.h:75:37: note:   ‘apache::thrift’
        Cassandra.h:4935:140: error: template argument 1 is invalid
        Cassandra.h: In constructor ‘org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::CassandraProcessor(boost::shared_ptr)’:
        Cassandra.h:4898:49: error: assignment of read-only location ‘"login"[((org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor*)this)->org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::processMap_]’
        Cassandra.h:4898:49: error: cannot convert ‘void (org::apache::cassandra::CassandraProcessor::*)(int32_t, int) {aka void (org::apach
```

Comment: Any luck with this problem?

Comment: Looks like a compiler issue

Answer (score 2):

Add the following defines:

```
g++ -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H ...
```

Or add `#include <stdint.h>` before including `Thrift.h` in your code.

See the discussion at [THRIFT-1326](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1326). The issue is suppposedly fixed in thrift 0.9.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is a compiler issue.

It can't find the type "uint32_t"

There is another question on SO regarding this:

['uint32_t' identifier not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162784/uint32-t-identifier-not-found-error)

Quoted from user **templatetypedef**

> This type is defined in the C header  which is not currently
>   a part of the C++ standard. According to the Wikipedia page on the
>   header, it hasn't shipped with Visual Studio until VS2010.
>
> In the meantime, you could probably fake up your own version of the
>   header by adding typedefs that map Microsoft's custom integer types to
>   the types expected by C. For example:
>
> typedef __int32 int32_t; typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t; /* ...
>   etc. ... */ Hope this helps!