# newer gcc gives illegal syntax error in a header file

Tags: c++, gcc

I've installed the [mimetic](http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html) library according to the INSTALL instructions.
the following main file compiles without a problem with a `gcc-c++ 4.1.2`,
but when I upgrade to `gcc-c++ 4.4.7` I get an error.

> mimetic.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mimetic.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mimetic;

int main()
{
    MimeEntity me;          
    return 0;
}
```

error

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/mimetic/rfc822/header.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/mimetic/header.h:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/mimetic/mimetic.h:18,
                 from mimetic.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/mimetic/rfc822/messageid.h:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘thread_id’
```

the header file:
rfc822/messageid.h

```
#ifndef _MIMETIC_MESSAGEID_H_
#define _MIMETIC_MESSAGEID_H_
#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
#include <string>
#include <mimetic/libconfig.h>
#ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
#include <inttypes.h>
#endif
#include <mimetic/utils.h>
#include <mimetic/os/utils.h>
#include <mimetic/rfc822/fieldvalue.h>

namespace mimetic
{
/// Message-ID field value 
/// On Win32 Winsock library must be initialized before using this class.
struct MessageId: public FieldValue
{
    MessageId(uint32_t thread_id = 0 ); // <------ line 29
    MessageId(const std::string&);
    std::string str() const;
    void set(const std::string&);
protected:
    FieldValue* clone() const;
private:
    static unsigned int ms_sequence_number;
    std::string m_msgid;
};
}
#endif
```

is there some compatibility switch for the gcc ?

Comment: I suspect your `HAVE_STDINT_H` or `HAVE_INTTYPES_H` are "wrong", so you don't get `uint32_t` included.

Comment: @Mats Petersson how can I check if these are correct ?

Comment: Try adding `#error this should give an error` next inside the `HAVE_STDINT_H`, to start with. If you don't get an error, then `HAVE_STDINT_H` is not set - which I'm pretty sure it should be [although, technically, since it's C++ code, it really should use `cstdint` - but I doubt it makes a difference].

Comment: You could try adding a -DHAVE_STDINT_H to your arguments to gcc and see if it works.  The proper way to make sure that flag is set is dependent on your build system.

Comment: Also, if your system _lacks_ `stdint.h`, you need to have replacement code that provides appropriate `typedef`s, or have your own abstracted types defined in terms of `stdint.h` types when present, or system-specific types if not.  As far as `cstdint` goes, I've worked with C++ compilers that provide `stdint.h` but not `cstdint`....

Comment: @Mats Petersson It worked! the HAVE_STDINT_H is not defined correctly, thus skipping the #include <stdint.h>. I just put the #include <stdint.h> outside the ifdef and it works ! I'll be happy to mark your answer as correct if you'll just post it

Comment: please check this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162784/uint32-t-identifier-not-found-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem turns out to be poor configuration of the system, which leaves HAVE_STDINT_H not configured, and thus the `uint32_t` doesn't get defined, and the error occurs.