# Why am I getting IntelliSense errors and how do I fix them or hide them?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, intellisense

When I build my C+ project in Visual Studio 2010 using Boost 1.54 and toolset v90, I get a bunch of IntelliSense errors (see image below).  My project still builds fine and runs as I'd expect.  These errors aren't preventing me from working on my code, but they are really annoying.  How do I either fix them or hide them?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162784/uint32-t-identifier-not-found-error) that mentions one of the errors.  It suggests that I include `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`.  I tried that but nothing changed.  I checked `greg_calendar.hpp` where the error is happening and it already includes `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`.

[image: IntelliSense errors]

Comment: Have you had a look at this page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519(v=vs.90).aspx - Basically just kill your intellisense cache by deleting the .ncb file in the directory where your solution is.

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio 2010 uses a *.sdf file instead.  I deleted that file to see what would happen.  When I re-opened my solution, Visual Studio recreated the file, but I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, don't know if this helps but my boost directory resides on D drive (D:/boost to be exact) and my project files also reside on D. My reference to it in the Visual Studio Include Directories was '\boost'. This compiled fine as it was on the same drive but intellisense was still saying I had errors so I changed it to be more explicit (D:\boost) and that fixed it up. Hope this helps anyone in the future.